# Grammar narration

Tags: reported-speech

What is the perfect answer of this question ?

Direct: He said to me "what is your name"?

Indirect: He asked me what my name is.

This indirect speech is correct or wrong. Please help me providing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of changes or transpositions you must make to turn direct discourse (a direct quote) into indirect discourse (a report of a quote). I'll use the the following example, in which you're waiting to hear a lecture in an auditorium on March 1st.

**Direct:** A man asks

> "Can<sub>1</sub> you<sub>2</sub> tell me<sub>2</sub> who is<sub>2</sub> speaking now<sub>3</sub> at this<sub>4</sub> lecture here<sub>4</sub> today<sub>3</sub>?"

At home, the next day, March 2nd, you want to report the question:

**Indirect:** A man asked whether

> I<sub>2</sub> could<sub>1</sub> tell him<sub>2</sub> who was<sub>1</sub> speaking then<sub>3</sub> at that<sub>4</sub> lecture there<sub>4</sub> yesterday<sub>3</sub>.

1. **Tense:** You received the question in the present, so the man used present tense *can* and *is*. The next day, that time of asking is in the past, so the verb forms change to indicate past with *could* and *was*.
2. **Person:** The man was talking to you about himself, so he used the second person pronoun *you* to address you and the first person pronoun *me* to talk about himself. But in a report you have to keep clear who was talking to whom. Thus when you talk about yourself, you need to transpose to the first person *I*, and when you talk about the man, you need to transpose to the third person *him*.
3. **Time:** When you were asked the question on March 1st the time was *now*, but the day of the report, *now* would refer to March 2nd. So you have to say *then*. Similarly, when the man asked the question *today* referred to March 1st, but at the time of the report *today* refers to March 2nd. To keep the date straight in the report, you have to say *yesterday* to report about March 1st.
4. **Proximity:** At the time of the question, *this* and *here* refer to something close by in time and place. Now that you're not near the auditorium and it's the next day, you have to indicate remoteness by using *that* and *there*, respectively.
5. **Sentence structure:** For an interrogative clause (a question), the auxiliary verb precedes the subject (*Can you*). For a declarative clause (a statement) like the report, the order must be reversed (*I could*).

Let's look at your example:

> **Direct:** He said to me "what is your name?"
>   **Indirect:** He asked me what my name is.

The sentence structure changes from interrogative (*is ... name?*) to declarative (*name is*). And the person changes from second (*your*) for the person addressed  to first (*my*). But what about the present tense *is*? Shouldn't it be transposed to the past:

> **Indirect:** He asked me what my name **was**.

That would be acceptable but not mandatory because the present tense may be used to describe events that obtained in the past and don't change. The canonical example is

> The earth revolves around the sun.

This is called the stative present. Since the stative present refers to past time (unchanging) events, it's not necessary to do the transposition.